# Allow enabling of screen after timeout

Tags: home-button, screen-timeout

I want to allow waking up of the screen either through using the home button or from a screen swipe or a tap on the screen BUT the screen should only wake up after a delay of say 5 seconds.  For example, here is the sequence of events:

1. screen has gone to sleep
2. user presses home button (or swipes or taps, whatever is easiest to wake up).
3. but the screen will not wake up until a set time delay has elapsed.
4. After time delay has elapsed instant reenabling of the screen is enabled.

Is there a setting or an app for this?